# How can I remove mysterious white-space?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

This is a very puzzling problem for me.

If you visit [this](http://screenpartner.norisp.no/~shift/) site on Safari there'll be added an extra 4-500px scrollable whitespace. Obviously it's not supposed to be like this, but I can't seem to grasp what creates this space :S

Inspecting reveals nothing to me, as it seems to be a part of the body, but there's no content in it, so why would it create the space?

If anyone could be able to help me that'd be great :)

Comment: Chrome ubuntu as well :-) because misery loves company.

Comment: this mistery also has the company of chrome on windows :-)

Comment: Curiously the extra space disappears after right-clicking an trying to inspect. Feels like a JS issue.

Comment: I have already had this kind of issue on a wesite with a sticky header that was set to position fixed with JS when user scrolled down but I didn't solve it.

Comment: @web-tiki you think that might be the problem. The site actually has a  plugin for a slide out menu when in mobile viewports and the site gets unscrollable (as it should) when pressing the menu icon..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to your `.shiftnav-wrap` class

```
height: auto;
```

Or add to your `wrapper` id

```
#wrapper {
  height: auto;
}
```

On your style.css

Comment: Thanks mate, this worked brilliantly :) Will accept your answer as soon as I'm allowed. EDIT, for some reason the problem came back after a refresh of the page..

Comment: I added the code to every css-file i could find. But spesifically custom.css because that's what the inspector said to add it to.

Comment: Is it fixed on your end now?

Comment: I had the code in the shiftnav.css. Or test on your "wrapper" id to add the code in your style.css

Comment: Tried both solutions, you can probably see when you inspect the code as well that I've added the rules. This site still giving me a hard time though..

Comment: Well, update your answer to adding overflow:hidden; to the #wrapper. That fixed it for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your body on the CSS

```
body{
    height: auto;
}
```