# CSS background stretches to fill height in iOS but there is white space on scroll

Tags: html, ios, css, background-image, stretch

this CSS gets my background to fill 100% of the screen height in iOS but there is a minor problem - when you scroll down there is initially white space, then when you release your finger and stop scrolling the background image "adjusts" and fills 100% of the screen height again. The problem does not re-occur on the same page if you continue to scroll, just the first time. Could someone please help? Thanks

```
#background {
  background: url(../img/background.jpg) center repeat-x;
  position: fixed;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1
}
```

Comment: iOS is not great with `position: fixed`. also, why do you need position:fixed to begin with? why not set the background to `<body>`?

Comment: I have a 50x1000 px background image pattern that I am trying to get to fill all screens (iOS and desktops) 100% width and 100% height, this is my crude solution to filling iOS 100% height

Comment: Did my solution not solve your problem?

Comment: your solution fills 100% of the page, not 100% of the screen on iOS

Comment: It would be great if you could reproduce your issue in Jsfiddle or other or link to your website because the problem might not come from the `#background` CSS itself.

Comment: I recently had this problem and we ended up needing to make a tileable background image and give up on position:fixed. In iOS the window height shrinks for the bottom menu bar, then expands when you scroll and the browser doesn't repaint the background quickly enough. We also abandoned this approach because the fixed full-height background div produced content flickering and re-rendering in Android native and Firefox when you scroll.

Comment: @cjspurg this is exactly my problem, can you give a coded solution? What approach did you end up using?

Comment: We didn't use a fixed background, we ended up adding a background to the content wrapper that scrolled with the content. The iOS and Android issues both seemed inherent to the way those mobile browsers handle `position:fixed`. Aka: not well. For just the iOS issue you could try setting `#background { height: 150% }`, but as I recall we still had the white bar. Sorry. :(

Comment: ok, height 150% didn't work for me, ive concluded its a mobile safari repainting issue like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365/how-can-i-force-webkit-to-redraw-repaint-to-propagate-style-changes, would there be a javascript solution? to force webkit to repaint the div before i release my finger? thats really the problem, everything is ok after you release your finger on scroll, just not before

Comment: The issue described in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22716660/how-can-i-remove-mysterious-white-space#comment34618145_22716660 seems to reflect what you are describing. Maybe it can help.

Comment: try this link, might be you can get solution here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629403/ios-colorwithpatternimage-stretch-image-full-screen

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens because your `#background` element is set to "follow" the height of the window:

```
#background {
    ...
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    ...
}
```

But, the `window` in Safari changes its size when you scroll down the content for the first time from `460px` to `529px`:

[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see from these screenshots, when the web page is loaded the `window.innerHeight` is equal to `460px` (on iPhone5). Then, when you begin scrolling the page down while your finger touches the screen the `window.innerHeight` is increased to `529px` but the content is not yet updated. Only when the finger is released from the screen the `#background` element is updated with the new window height which equals to `529px`.

To fix this issue you should make sure that the `#background` element is higher than the initial window height by `529-460 = 69px`. Or the `#background` element has constant height of `529px` (or higher):

```
#background {
    ...
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: -69px;
    ...
}
```

OR

```
#background {
    ...
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    /* use height instead of bottom */
    height: 529px;
    ...
}
```

Here is a final code that fixes this issue:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Fixed background</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
        <style>
            #background {
                background: url(bkgd.png) repeat;
                position: fixed;
                background-size: 100% auto;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: -69px;
                z-index: -1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="background"></div>
        <div style="height: 5000px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just solved this issue. The problem for me was that the whitespace was showing when I had my body tag with a background-image, with the background-size set to cover. To fix this issue I set:

`background-size: 100vw 100vh;`

Then set the media query I was having the problem with to

```
{background-size: cover;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using viewport units on the background

`background-size: 100vw 100vh;`

But first add viewport meta tag to your page:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`

**NOTE:**

The vw and vh units are not fully supported, check out the supported browsers [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=vw).

Comment: "vh" has very unexpected behavior in iOS (and soon in Android) especially between Safari and Chrome despite them using the same renderer the UI toolbar elements that move around on-scroll is what causes the issue. You can read more about it here - https://nicolas-hoizey.com/2015/02/viewport-height-is-taller-than-the-visible-part-of-the-document-in-some-mobile-browsers.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not use background-size: cover. That way the background image will always fill its attached div or body tag

Comment: Nope...  this is the most obvious answer, but it doesn't work on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

`<name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0," />`

body{
background-size: cover;

}

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by using long transition delays to prevent the element resizing.

eg:

```
transition: height 250ms 600s; /*10min delay*/
```

The tradeoff with this is it prevents resizing of the element including on device rotating, however you could use some JS to detect orientationchange and reset the height if this was an issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
html, body {
    display: block;
    height:  100%;
    width:   100%;
}

body {
    background-image:      url('some/image.jpg');
    background-repeat:     repeat-x;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position:   center center;
    background-size:       contain;
}
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6YjgZ/1/)